# Wrapping graphQL(appsync) with REST API using Amazon api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-api-gateway

I have a graphQL server deployed with aws appsync. The thing is that our customers prefer a standard REST API. I'm looking for the simplest way to wrap graphQL query with REST API.

I'm considering using Amazon api gateway to make a REST endpoint, and integrate lambda behind the api gateway. In that way I can let lambda functions to send a fixed graphQL query/mutations and modify the response.

However as you can see from below image, I found AWS Service integration option in Amazon API gateway. I'm wondering whether I can integrate appsync to api gateway directly without using lambda. I searched it from aws documents but couldn't find any related information.

Amazon api gateway setup capture:

[image: Amazon api gateway setup capture]

1. Is it possible to wrap graphQL API with REST API by integrating appsync to api gateway without using lambda? Just like what I found from the captured image?
2. If yes, is there any examples or tutorials?
3. If not, should I just integrate lambda? Is there any better ideas or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to integrate appsync to API gateway. 
You can do it with AWS Service integration by setting it as AppSync Data Plane.

In the method setup page:

1. Integration type = AWS Service
2. AWS Service = AppSync Data Plane
3. AWS Subdomain = get it from your appsync endpoint
   (For example: 
   https://YOUR_AWS_Subdomain.appsync-api.your-region.amazonaws.com/graphql)
4. HTTP method = POST
5. Action Type = Use path override
6. Path override(optional) = graphql

It worked well for me.

Comment: Hi @BSD, Can you pls share the execution role you created? I tried your steps and created an execution role(from another Medium post - https://medium.com/@aswinkumar4018/aws-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-to-appsync-5d4dcd609a2c) as below - {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "appsync:GraphQL"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:{AWS-Account-Number}:apis/{AppSync-API-ID}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: but I get error - Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role

Comment: @csharpnewbie make sure the role has enough permissions to call appsync

Comment: @BSD how do format the request for the rest api? wouldn't the body be the same as a graphql query? If so what is the point in creating a proxy rather than just making the appsync public

Answer (score 1):

In case someone using OpenAPI spec for defining APIGW, use the following:

```
/graphql:
  post:
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      type: "AWS"
      httpMethod: "POST"
      uri: arn:aws:apigateway:<APIGW_REGION>:<APPSYNC_URL_ID>.appsync-api:path/graphql
      credentials: <INVOCATION_ROLE_ARN>
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/appsync.html#appsync_region_data_plane
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#type

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to construct the uri for OpenAPI Spec. Is there a way to get this dynamically in terraform? e.g. aws_appsync_graphql_api.mygraphql.arn did not work

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @BSD's solution:

- IAM role:

  - should grant Trust relationship to ApiGateway

    ```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Condition": {}
        }
      ]
    }
    ```
  - should have policy to allow to access AppSync endpoint

    ```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "appsync:GraphQL"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:appsync:us-east-1:{AWS-Account-Number}:apis/{AppSync-API-ID}/*"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }
    ```
- The format for sending query/mutation through APIGW:
  Let's say your AppSync query is:

```
query MyQuery {
  foo(request: {bar: "abc123", baz: "xyz"}) {
    a
    b
    c
  }
}
```

This query turns into the following JSON:

```
{
  "query": "query MyQuery {foo(request: {bar: \"abc123\", baz: \"xyz\"}) {a b c} }"
}
```